# Use statement for child classes

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, model-view-controller

I have a `Controller` class in which I have to use several namespaces like :

```
<?php

use Respect/Validation/Validator;
use Blah/blah/Foo;

class Controller {}
```

Now what I want that in every controller files that extends my `Controller` class, I do not have to write the use statements again and again.

This is something I want similar to what Laravel has done in his alias section.

How would I achieve this thing ? So for example when I do :

```
<?php
class HomeController extends Controller {
   public function index()
   {
       $data = '';
       Validator::arr($data); // Validator not found
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately what you would have to do if using static methods. You could also have a Controller method (the constructor even) to inject the validator into the class, which the child classes can then use. You would the use public instance variables on the validator.

The benefit is that you do not need to specify the NS for your dependencies again and, especially so, your code is cleaner since you do not have a hard dependency on the Validator class.

Comment: Good solution but this would make the class holding unnecessary instances even if the child class is not going to use them.

Comment: If it's optional, you can pass a Validator factory to the constructor and instantiate the object only if called upon. You could also have a setter and getter rather than passing through the constructor so you only set it when it's required. However, if you're concerned about it, specifying the namespace and using DI to pass to the child classes constructor is the way to go.

Comment: your answers are too high for me to understand i am not pro :) If you could update your answer with a example i would be thankful to you. I am trying to understand your points but example code would be much helpful thanks.

Comment: I'm on my iPhone at the moment but I will create an example for you tomorrow :)

Comment: Thanks ! The Validator Factory you mentioned i am more interested in that.

Comment: I think what he's trying to say is that if you have an _instance_ of a validator rather than utilizing the static method on the facade, then your child controller can access `$this->validator` and it shouldn't need to care at all what type `$this->validator` is

Comment: oh i see, Since my concern towards using composer packages. So you see `Respect\Validation\Validator`is using all static. Some other package would be using instance. The goal is not relying just on my code but if a framework user add some more packages via composer i want him not to bother writing `use` statements over and over ideally in a single place.